# Nginx + Wordpress: Redirect URLs after moving to Wordpress

Tags: nginx, wordpress, 301-redirect

I have a classified ads website using a proprietary script and now I am moving it to Wordpress. I want to redirect the old URLs to Wordpress URLs.
The script has two main URL types:

1. Category URL:
   /category/id-of-category[/page-number]/category-name.html
   eg.:
   /category/15/cars.html
   /category/15/3/cars.html  (the 3 is for pagination)
   it should redirect to /?cat=15
2. Listing URL:
   /category/id-of-category/category-name/listings/id-of-ad/ad-title.html
   eg.:
   /category/15/cars/listings/12345/selling-my-old-toyota.html
   it should redirect to /?p=12345

I want to know the exact nginx configuration that would do the permanent redirection to new URL on the same domain name.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing of the page number ?

Anyway, assuming `id-of-*` and page number can be represented by at least one character of range `[0-9]` and `category-name` and `ad-title` can be represented by at least one character of range `[_-a-zA-Z0-9]` :

```
location ~ ^/category/(\d+)/?\d*/[-\w]+\.html$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name/?cat=$1;
}

location ~ ^/category/\d+/[-\w]+/listings/(\d+)/[-\w]+\.html$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$server_name/?p=$1;
}
```

Note that nginx regular expressions are a bit particular but very powerfull (e.g. add minus sign to alphanumeric range without the need to rewrite the entire range `[-_a-zA-Z0-9]` in detail as you would do with grep for instance).

**Update** : fixed second location catpure group.

Comment: the first location was always catching urls of the second, i think the problem is with [-\W]+

Comment: the page number is for pagination if the category contains many listings then there will be several pages.

Comment: I solved it follows:  
location ~ ^/category/\d+/[^./\"'?#]+/listings/(\d+)/[^./\"'?#]+.html$ { return 301 /?p=$1;}  
location ~ ^/category/(\d+)(/\d+)?/[^./\"'?#]+.html$ {return 301 /?ad-cat=$1;}

Comment: @bml13 You are right. In fact It was matching the second regex but the capture group was wrong (category name instead of the ad id). Updated answer.